# Restore diff backup only on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is there a way to restore ONLY a differential backup on SQL Server?

I have a situation where I only need to view one table that was truncated from an entire database.  And instead of trying to restore the entire massive database in it's entirety, I wanted to try and restore only the differential and check to see the condition of that table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the differential backup is based on the differences since the main.  It doesn't contain a full usable structure.